# ofstream object as variable

Tags: c++, object, variables, ofstream

I am trying to create multiple files according to a filename in cpp. Using `ofstream` for that, I could not achieve it for now.

I'd appreciate if anyone can help me with that.

I am writing down here:

```
static std::ofstream text1;
static std::ofstream text2;

class trial{
public:
  if(situation == true) {
    document_type = text1;
  }
  if(situation == false) {
    document_type = text2;
  }

  document_type << "hello world" << "\n";
}
```

ofstream object as variable.

Comment: Before anyone can help you,  you have to state what your _specific problem_ is.

Comment: Stack Overflow is [a question and answer site](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  Before posting a question, you should make sure that you have a question to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assignment *copies* the objects, and it's not possible to create copies of streams. You can only have reference to streams, and you can't reassign references.

Instead I suggest you pass a reference to the wanted stream to the `trial` constructor instead, and store the reference in the object:

```
struct trial
{
    trial(std::ostream& output)
        : output_{ output }
    {
    }

    void function()
    {
        output_ << "Hello!\n";
    }

    std::ostream& output_;
};

int main()
{
    bool condition = ...;  // TODO: Actual condition

    trial trial_object(condition ? text1 : text2);
    trial_object.function();
}
```

---

Also note that I use plain `std::ostream` in the class, which allows you to use *any* output stream, not only files.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use statements at class scope, only declarations.

In any case, you need to use a reference variable for what you are attempting, eg:

```
std::ofstream& document_type = situation ? text1 : text2;
document_type << "hello world" << "\n";
```